# Package error after adding web reference to script component in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, web-services, reporting-services, ssis

I'm following the instructions I could find online to try generating SSRS reports via SSIS package.

But whenever I add the SSRS report web services reference, the pack will throw me a package validation error.

Something like "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.CannotCreateUserComponentException: Cannot create user component class. Make sure there is one class marked with SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute in your script."

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can show us how/what you add when you say you add a reference because this looks like you have modified the main entry point of the script which can happen if you have syntax issues or delete the wrong thing etc.

Comment: Hi Matt, it seems like my laptop does not have the Win SDK installed.  Going to test it later.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If using VS2017 or VS2019, verify `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> TargetServerVersion -> SQL Server 2014 (or newer)`, also, verify that when building script you have the SDK version that the script is using to build per-se